# Why does the relative permittivity of Sapphire not match the square of its refractive index?

Tags: optics, refraction, dielectric

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire), the refractive index of sapphire is around $n = 1.8$ while its relative permittivity $\varepsilon_{\mathrm r}$ is between $9$ and $11$ (depending on the direction). Given that sapphire is not magnetic, I would expect
$$
n = \sqrt{\varepsilon_{\mathrm r}}
$$
to hold. The values above are quite far off this relation, though.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both index of refraction and permitivity are frequency dependent parameters. The index of refraction is measured at frequencies in the visible range whereas the dielectric permitivity given in the OP is for electrostatic field (or at least very low frequency). The same question is usualy asked about water, with its permitivity of about 80, as measured in DC regime and index of refraction (visible range frequencies) of about 1.3. If you want the realtionship to hold you need both values for the same frequency range. At visible frequencies the dielectric constant is lower than in the static regime.